# Dirichlet regression using jags

Tags: jags, compositional-data

I am trying to fit a simple Dirichlet regression using rjags with a parametrization in terms of the mean and the precision. The model is written as follows:

model {
    # (0) priors 
    for (i in 1:(k-1))
    {
      beta0[i] ~ dnorm(0,1);
    }
    theta1 ~ dnorm(0, 4)

```
# (1) likelihood 
for (j in 1:n){
  p1[j,] ~ ddirch(a1[]);
}

# Parametrization in terms of the mean and the precision
for (i in 1:(k-1))
{
  a1[i] <- mu1[i]*phi1
  mu1[i] <- exp(beta0[i])/(1+ exp(beta0[i]))
}
a1[k] <- (1 - sum(mu1[1:(k-1)]))*phi1
phi1 <- exp(theta1)
```

}

I continuously get the same error:

Error in node p1[1,1:4]
Invalid parent values

I think that it is due to the substraction (1 - sum(mu1[1:(k-1)])), which is giving negative values. Any ideas of how can I solve that?